# Как правильно сериализовать многомерный массив C# в JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serializable

Собираю List вида int[,]

```
    for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--)
        {
            var q = (int)(DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0)).DayOfWeek;
            var w = new Random().Next(200);
            int[,] e = new int[q, w];
            obj.Add(e);
        }
        string json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(obj);
```

Хочу что бы на выходе в JSON было вот так

```
    [[0, 0], [1, 10], [2, 23], [3, 17], [4, 18], [5, 9]]
```

Но на выходе совершенно другое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно нужно сделать?

Comment: Но то что вы хотите - не многомерный массив. Это список пар.

Comment: Меня одного смущает вот эта строка `int[,] e = new int[q, w];` ? То, что тут происходит - небольшая тайна и магия и уж точно это не попытка записать значения в переменную. Это попытка на каждом шаге создать массив с длиной в q элементов и шириной w элементов ?

Comment: А может, вам нужен jagged array? И да, какой тип у `obj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы делаете вот в этой строке

`int[,] e = new int[q, w];`

Тут вы инициализирует **двумерный массив** который будет содержать нули. Причем в вашем случае может быть например массив п[10,100] и он будет наполнен нулями (int по умолчанию).

Чтобы все таки сделать так, как вы хотите - то заполняйте этот массив ( который будет например int[1,2] для пар значений.
Или используейте `Dictionary <int,int>()`.
Однако я не уверен по поводу сериализации при использовании int[]

Comment: Пометьте данный ответ, как правильный (галочка <--- слева от вопроса), если он вам помог и содержит полезную информацию. Если же нет, то напишите свой ответ. Этим вы поможете кому-то в будующем. Спасибо